# how can I use grep/awk or any scripting methodology in order to aggregate time input lines (for example by second)

Tags: linux, awk, grep

how can I use grep/awk or any scripting methodology in order to aggregate time input lines (for example by second)
for example:

I have the input:

```
13:27:53.336281
13:27:53.336284
13:27:53.346284
13:27:54.336435
13:27:54.336468
```

if I need the output

```
13:27:53 3
13:27:54 2
```

Comment: With `grep`, that's fairly impossible.

Comment: it not must be grep.

Answer (score 5):

```
cut -f 1 -d . input.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: perhaps add `... uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'` to match the desired output format

Comment: Assuming the input is already sorted, the solution becomes `cut -f 1 -d . input.txt | uniq -c |  awk '{print $2,$1}', which is an economical pipeline with minimal memory requirements (unlike the accepted answer).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you can do what you want using grep but awk is capable:

```
awk -F. 'NR > 1 && $1 != prev { print prev, count; count = 0 } 
         { prev = $1; ++count } 
         END { print prev, count }' file
```

The output is printed whenever `prev` doesn't match the current value of the first field, `$1`. The first record is skipped as `prev` has not yet been set. The middle block applies to all records and increments the count. The `END` block ensures that the results for the final time are printed.

The other option is to use an associative array but if you do that, the results will be unsorted. Also, if your file is huge, then memory consumption may be an issue (this method only ever stores `prev` and `count` so memory usage is independent of the size of the file).

Answer (score 1):

Since question has `awk` tag, here is an `awk` solution.

```
$ cat input.txt 
13:27:53.336281
13:27:53.336284
13:27:53.346284
13:27:54.336435
13:27:54.336468
$ awk -F'.' '{ aa[$1]++ } END{ for (key in aa) print key " " aa[key]}' input.txt 
13:27:53 3
13:27:54 2
```

**Update:** As indicated in the comment, order of the output is not guaranteed. Therefore, it could be necessary to pipe the `awk` output to `sort`.

Comment: Note that the order of array traversal using `for (key in array)` is undefined, so the output isn't guaranteed to be in order.